# Composable TimePicker does not set the time to 23:50

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have an seeing this issue with composable TimePicker, which uses a timePickerState - rememberTimePickerState. to test this I am setting manually the time to be 23:59 but the displayed time in the TimePicker is 12:59.

Note: any other time I set works fine, it is just when I set hours to 23, it shows as 12.
Also tested with both 12 hours and 24 hours, it is the same issue.

Any one has seen this behaviour?

```
val timePickerState = rememberTimePickerState(
    initialHour = 23,
    initialMinute = 59
)

 TimePicker(
            state = timePickerState,
            colors = TimePickerDefaults.colors(
                clockDialColor = md_theme_accessible_blue,
                timeSelectorSelectedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                timeSelectorSelectedContentColor = md_theme_accessible_blue,
                timeSelectorUnselectedContainerColor = md_theme_accessible_blue,
                periodSelectorSelectedContainerColor = md_theme_accessible_blue,
                periodSelectorSelectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                periodSelectorUnselectedContainerColor = md_theme_accessible_blue,
            )
        )
```

This is what I see on the timePicker
[image]

Could you suggest anything I could try to resolve this please

Thanks
R

Edit:
Gradle

```
//Compose
val composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00")
implementation(composeBom)
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha05")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug that has been already fixed: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2443699

Works fine for me with the latest version of material3 library (`1.2.0-alpha05`). Try updating.

Comment: Hello @Jan Bina, one query, just noticed that using alpha-05 works fine on Debug builds but have the same issue on release build, I have updated the question with gradle related to compose. could you spot anything I might be doing wrong please